# how we get custom header attributes which pass in https secure header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to get header attributes from http header by

```
request.headers
```

But in case of HTTPS i fail to get custom header attributes.

so my concern is how i get custom attributes in case of HTTPS.

Comment: Could you explain the behavior expected vs what's happening? With some code?

Comment: when request comes from HTTP then i will get my custom header attributes value by request.headers['X-CUSTOM-SOURCE'] but problem is that when request comes from HTTPS(secure HTTP) then request.headers['X-CUSTOM-SOURCE'] gives nill value

Comment: Describe your configuration: is SSL being managed by Rails or are you using a reverse proxy to offload SSL?

Comment: In my case SSL is managed by Rails.. 
{ config.force_ssl = true}

Comment: Show the contents of `request.headers` when running in each mode.